# coverage/index.html is not found after running rspec spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-rcov'
```

included

```
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

in spec_helper.rb class and ran the rpec/spec . But after running that when I navigate to 0.0.0.0:3000/coverage/index.html um getting this error

Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/coverage/index.html"

what can possibly go wrong in here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: not sure if simplecov behaves differently with rails, but i'd suggest you look for the coverage folder in your app's root folder (look for changed files if you're using version control). if you find it, you can just open the index.html in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'simplecov'
gem 'simplecov-rcov'
```

And run `bundle install`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of pasting the url into your browser, try running this in your terminal:

```
open coverage/index.html
```

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/252-metrics-metrics-metrics for more details.

Comment: It worked!  But why is this different from entering the URL into a browser?

Comment: @intcreator Because the rails web server isn't designed to serve your coverage report. (The rails web server at 0.0.0.0:3000 is designed to mimic a public web server, and you probably wouldn't want to show your coverage report to the world.) By running "open coverage/index.html", your web browser opens the coverage report as a local file, instead of going through the rails web server.